# Decreasing a integer every second

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am using AndEngine to add sprites to a scene.

The sprites are all added at a Timed interval that I can control through a class i created for it.

For Example to set the time(as second)

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.setInterval(Float second);
```

I created this method so that the timer could change as i needed it to during the user interaction with the game.

So as the sprites are added to the scene they move on the y axis at random places.

I have two intervals that they take to control the max duration and minimum duration they take to move across the screen.

For example...

```
Private int MaxDurarion = 4;// 4 is equivalent to 4 seconds for this
Private int MinDuration = 2 //Same for minimum duration
```

I have a IUpdateHandler that is designed to be updated every second.

So in this method i update the score and other things accordingly.

Now the problem is i check to see if the user has reached a certain score, if they have then i would like to decrease the max duration and the minimum duration.

For Example..

```
if(userScore == MAX){
MaxDuration = MaxDuration - (int).2;
TimerSecond = TimerSecond - .1f;
}
```

Now i have tried it this way, but i have found that the Maxduration returns back to the original integer after each update.

I hope ive explained this well enough what i am trying to do.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are casting `.2` to an `int` which I believe is resulting in 0, so you aren't changing the `MaxDuration` at all.

Comment: Hmm good point. So how do you think i could wourk around this? If i change the MaxDuration to a double the method recieving the duration wont accept it unless i use (int)Double.

Comment: @coder_for_life22 If that is the functionality you need then do it.

Comment: 4 - .2 is 3.8 which is a double..Could this be cast to a int?

Comment: It would be cast to `4` until it got to `3.4` then it would be cast to `3`. If you're talking about pixels the user can't see fractions of a pixel so they won't know the difference.

Comment: Nevermind, you're talking about time, what method accepts time as seconds? Everything I do time related in my games is on a millisecond level.

Comment: AndEngines MoveModifier method.

Comment: @coder_for_life22 Well, the double approach will be your best bet then I think.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that (int) 0.2 will resolve to zero due to reounding the decimal into an integer. So Maxduration always has nothing subtracted from it.

Comment: Hmm good point. So how do you think i could wourk around this? If i change the MaxDuration to a double the method recieving the duration wont accept it unless i use (int)Double

Comment: if the method receiveing the duration only accepts an int, you can only lower it by an int also. But yes, making maxDuration a float, so that you can decrement it would also work. Or you could just decrement it by 1 every 5 seconds instead of .2 ever second. Eithe way, the solution will appear the same to the end user.